# /groups/{id}/planner/plans with odata.metadata=full returns Bad Request

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

A request to the following Graph endpoint (and some others) is resulting in an error:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<id>/planner/plans
```

400 Bad Request - (Unexpected token LEFT BRACE({) at position 174.)

```
{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.plannerPlan)","@odata.count":1,"value":[{"@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.plannerPlan"{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "When writing a JSON response, a user model must be specified and the entity set and entity type must be passed to the ODataMessageWriter.CreateODataEntryWriter method or the ODataFeedAndEntrySerializationInfo must be set on the ODataEntry or ODataFeed that is being written.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "e6824e3f-9519-4f2a-a68e-968bc4d16c6b",
      "date": "2017-05-22T16:52:22"
    }
  }
}
```

This URL on the other hand works fine.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<id>/planner
```

Both of these are in the presence of the headers:

```
Accept: application/json;odata.metadata=full
Authorization: Bearer <AccessToken>
```

It looks like it is the odata.metadata=full causing the first request to fail.

The error can be seen by using the
[**Graph Explorer**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=groups/d174fcb7-6569-4f8a-84c2-907d34826d4e/planner/plans&method=GET&version=v1.0) and setting only the request header
**Accept: application/json;odata.metadata=full**
(this uses a sample account so the Authorization header is not required).

(Note it returns a valid response if "/plans" is stripped from the end of the URL.  It also seems to work if the group contains no plans)

Comment: Where does the `value` come from? Are you POSTING any JSON? The first line contains the error at the very end, `"value":[{"@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.plannerPlan"{` where the last `{` is unexpected.

Comment: This was the response when using Restlet Client in chrome

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to show all the code required to make the outgoing request?

Comment: It is reproducable without code, using chrome and your favourite rest client.  Just set the Authorization and Accept header.

Comment: Please post your code, or a reproducible example. I do not have any authorization tokens, so for me, all I receive is a 400 telling me that I am not authorized. I never see the 400 due to invalid JSON.

Comment: I added the link to the graph explorer - this can be used without the authorization header